# jQuery plugin for freezing header, freezing columns, column resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

On my current project I need to add the following functionality to tables:

- Freezing table header
- Freezing one or more columns on the left
- Ability to re-size columns

We are using RichFaces and jQuery. I have searched for jQuery plugins, but each of them lacks at least one of these features. Could anyone advise a jQuery plugin that provides **all** of these features out of the box?

Comment: When you say "Freezing header row", do you mean freezing the header of the table or freezing the 1st row apart from the header?

Comment: I mean "freezing the header of the table"

Comment: http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Comment: Thanks. But jqGrid requires specifying colmodel for each table and I since I have huge amount of tables and columns in them and I am limited in time, I would like a plugin that does not require configuration of metadata for columns. Any suggestion?.

Comment: hmmm.. if you have a backend or MVC architecture, you can dynamically create the colModel in your template. If its a static page, why not just write a small script that generates the colModel codes. Just a random thought. I do not have any other suggestion :| (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277962/jqgrid-and-dynamic-column-binding for reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) covers all of these required features.

Please see the following [demos](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) for each of the feature

1. Freeze header - True scrolling rows
2. Freeze columns - Frozen columns
3. Re-size columns - This feature is present by default but you can always use make them fixed width columns if required. Documentation is pretty good.

Comment: Thanks. But jqGrid requires specifying colmodel for each table and I since I have huge amount of tables and columns in them and I am limited in time, I would like a plugin that does not require configuration of metadata for columns. Any suggestion?