# loading columns dynamically for JQGrid using AjaxCall

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I need to load columns to Jqgrid Dynamically and am trying to follow  [jqGrid and dynamic column binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277962/jqgrid-and-dynamic-column-binding)

Am trying in MVC. for Column name am fetching from Table(Which has a list of Columns to be displayed in GRID)  and returning the Json data which is straightforward.

How do i implement for ColModel. For ex: i need to send JSon object like this dynamically

```
     {name: 'Airport', formatter: UrlFmatter, width: 95, align: "center", index: 'AIRPORT', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'cn']} }
  {name: 'Country', width: 100, align: "center", index: 'Country', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'cn']} }
```

How my design should be to send  json to set the colModel ?

My UrlFmatter code

```
function UrlFmatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                    return "<a href='DetailResult?airportname=" + options.rowId + "' >" + cellvalue + "</a>";
                }
```

How do i write as per your answer for formatting and unformatting ?
Thanks

Comment: do you need change the state of the grid ready or before?

Comment: i need to send data from DB and assign it to COlModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you have the problem with sending information about the formatter (`formatter: UrlFmatter`) inside of JSON. JSON strings don't support functions as the type of data. The most easy way to solve the problem seems me registering your formatter in the same way as standard formatters. For example is you want that your formatter have the name `"myUrlFormatter"` you can use the following

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    /*jslint unparam: true */
    $.extend($.fn.fmatter, {
        myUrlFormatter: function (cellValue, options) {
            // you should place here the code of 
            // your custom formatter UrlFmatter
        }
    });
    $.extend($.fn.fmatter.myUrlFormatter, {
        unformat: function (cellValue, options, elem) {
            // you should place here the code of 
            // your custom unformatter
        }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

You should include the code *after* `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` (or after `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`). After such registration of the formatter you can use it in `colModel` as

```
{name: "Airport", index: "AIRPORT", formatter: "myUrlFormatter", width: 95,
    align: "center", searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "cn"]} }
```

So the value of `formatter` property will be **string** (`formatter: "myUrlFormatter"`) instead of the function (`formatter: UrlFmatter`).