# Sending single JSON Data to Jquery Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I'm following this link [jqGrid and dynamic column binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277962/jqgrid-and-dynamic-column-binding)  to generate dynamic columns for JQGrid

In my MVC Controller I have 2 functions one for Column name and another for Colmodel

```
   GetColumnNamesForGrid()  //  Json Array

    GetColumnModelForGrid()   // Json Object
```

Both the functions returning the JSON Data which am planning to assign to the JqGrid ColModel and ColName.

Now I have to call functions and I need to send both the results in  a Single call and I'll will fetch in Ajax like

```
success: function (result) {
                 colN = result.colname;
                 colM = result.item.colModel;
```

Something like this.

How can I do this? I'm stuck here because I'm new to these languages.

Please let me know if there is any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the second answer in the referred SO question link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7846175/206766

[ASP.NET MVC and a Generic jQuery Grid -jqTGrid](http://blog.lieberlieber.com/2010/07/07/asp-net-mvc-and-a-generic-jqquery-grid-jqtgrid/)