# Length of Colnames <> Colmodel issue JQGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jqgrid

Am trying to load Columns to JQGrid Dynamically using Ajax calls as mentioned here [jqGrid and dynamic column binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277962/jqgrid-and-dynamic-column-binding)

i just did a sample with 1 column. My Column name JSON

```
"Data":["Airport"]  which working just fine.
```

and the issue is with ColumnModel  JSON below

```
{"colModelData":{"items":[{"name":"Airport"}]}
```

Itz not working. How do i need to change my JSON so that JQGrid accepts

how can i make it work ??

Thanks

Comment: I think it just needs the `"name":"Airport"` part. The parsing error could be coming due to the problem that it is wrapped in items. And instead of a string it finds an object array

Comment: Nothing to do with your particular problem, but this error also comes up also when the number of colNames mismatches the number of ColModel columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you just use the posted data in the wrong way. Probably you use `colModel: result.colModelData` instead of `colModel: result.colModelData.items` which more corresponds the JSON data.

By the way you can use `label` property in items of `colModel` and *don't specify any `colNames`*.