# Length of colnames <> colmodel when using dynamic colNames & colModel

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

In my mvc **jqgrid** code, colnames and colmodel returning same length of col. but when run the application im getting this error. Any help?

Code :

```
public WeekColumns GetWeekColumns(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        WeekColumns week = new WeekColumns();

        string sWeekDate = string.Empty;

        var model = db.GetWeek(start.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"),
            end.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")).ToList().Select(s => s.WeekDate.ToString());

        IEnumerable<string> sModel = new List<string>();
        sModel = model;

        string sColumnNames = "['ID', 'Account', 'Lob'";

        foreach (string item in sModel)
            sColumnNames += ", 'C" + item.ToString().Replace("/", "_").Trim() + "'";

        sColumnNames += ", 'Report']";

        string sColumnModels = "[{ name: 'ID', key: true, hidden: true }, ";
        sColumnModels += "{ name: 'Account', width: 150, align: 'center' }, ";
        sColumnModels += "{ name: 'Lob', width: 150, align: 'center' }";

        foreach (string item in sModel)
            sColumnModels += ", { name: 'C" + item.ToString().Replace("/", "_").Trim() + 
                "', width: 150, editable: true}";

        sColumnModels += ", { name: 'Report', width: 150, align: 'center' }]";

        week.ColumnName = sColumnNames;
        week.ColumnModel = sColumnModels;

        return week;
    }
```

js :

```
$.ajax({
        url: "Staffing/GetWeekDate",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#jqTable").jqGrid({
                // Ajax related configurations
                url: "Staffing/LOBStaffing",
                datatype: "json",
                mtype: "POST",
                //ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
                jsonReader: {
                    root: 'rows',
                    page: 'page',
                    total: 'total',
                    records: 'records',
                    repeatitems: true,
                    data: 'data'
                },

                // Specify the column names
                colNames: data.ColumnName,

                // Configure the columns
                colModel: data.ColumnModel,

                // Grid total width and height  
                width: 900,
                height: 350,

                sortname: 'Lob',
                // Paging
                rowList: [],        // disable page size dropdown
                pager: $("#jqTablePager"),
                pgbuttons: false,     // disable page control like next, back button
                pgtext: null,         // disable pager text like 'Page 0 of 10'
                viewrecords: true,
                rowNum: 2000,

                grouping: true,
                groupingView: {
                    groupField: ['Account', 'Lob'],
                    groupColumnShow: [true, true],
                    groupText: ['<b>{0}</b>'],
                    groupCollapse: false,
                    groupOrder: ['asc', 'asc'],
                    groupSummary: [true, true]
                },

                // Grid caption
                caption: "List of Forms"
            }).navGrid("#jqTablePager",
                {
                    refresh: true,
                    add: false,
                    edit: false,
                    del: false,
                    search: false,
                    refreshtext: "Refresh",
                    searchtext: "Search"
                },
                {}, // settings for edit
                {}, // settings for add
                {}, // settings for delete
                {multipleGroup: true }, // settings for search,
                {
                multipleGroup: true,
                sopt: ["cn", "eq"],
                caption: "Search",
                Find: "Search"
            }); // Search options. Some options can be set on column level

        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you show your grid code and code where you form rows and cols?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The values of `colNames` and `colModel` should be **arrays** of items of the same size. It seems that your current code try to assign **strings** with the text like `"['ID', 'Account', 'Lob', ...]"` and `"[{ name: 'ID', key: true, hidden: true }, ...]"`. The code of jqGrid which try to compare the number of items in **arrays** `colNames` and `colModel` (see [here](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid/blob/v4.7.0/js/grid.base.js#L1077-L1080)) compare the length of the **strings** which you use as the values of `colNames` and `colModel`. So the displayed message is mot correct, but your input data are still wrong.

So to solve the problem you have to fix the format (**change the type**) of `data.ColumnName` and `data.ColumnModel`.

You can for example replace `'` in `data.ColumnName` and `data.ColumnModel` to `\"`. It makes the strings as correct JSON trings and you could use `$.parseJSON()` (I mean just `colNames: $.parseJSON(data.ColumnName), colModel: $.parseJSON(data.ColumnModel)`).

Comment: Thanks oleg. I've replaced `'` to `/` and still got some errors. INVALID JSON.

Comment: I suggested to replace `'` to `"` . If you use `"` in C# inside of another string it should be escaped. So you need replace `string sColumnModels = "[{ name: 'ID', key: true, hidden: true }, ";` to `string sColumnModels = "[{ name: \"ID\", key: true, hidden: true }, ";` for example. You should do the same with all options.

Comment: Hi @Oleg, Already changed the code but still have some errors. 

**ColumnName:**
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ':' after property name in object at line 1 column 7 of the JSON data

`"[{"ID", "Account", "Lob", "C01_04_2015", "C01_11_2015", "C01_18_2015", "C01_25_2015", "Report"}]"`

Comment: **ColumnModel**
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 4 of the JSON data

`"[{ name: "ID", key: true, hidden: true }, { name: "Account", width: 150, align: "center" }, { name: "Lob", width: 150, align: "center" }, { name: "C01_04_2015", width: 150, editable: true}, { name: "C01_11_2015", width: 150, editable: true}, { name: "C01_18_2015", width: 150, editable: true}, { name: "C01_25_2015", width: 150, editable: true}, { name: "Report", width: 150, align: "center" }]"`

Comment: Hi @Oleg! It worked! I just made some changes on my string output using the online JSON parser. Thank you!!

Comment: @JVELASCO, exactly what did you do convert the strings to JSON array?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `colModel: data.ColumnModel` to `colModel: data.ColumnModel.items` it's from @Oleg [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15473953/1849444).

Sometimes i think @Oleg already answer to all **jqgrid** related questions...

Comment: thanks teo for the response. i've already change columnModel > columnModel.items. jqgrid worked but there's no data to show. when I checked it on FireBUg, ColumnModel.items = 'undefined'. Am I missing something on my code? or my ColumnModel are properly setup? Thanks in advance!

Comment: i suppose it happends becouse you have you `columnModel` field as a `string`, i think `Json()` method in controller serialize it wrong way, unexpected for `jqgrid`. try to change it to `List<string>` and add each row data.

Answer (score 0):

You can omit using colNames array. It is beter to use colModel with set of label

the code

`colNames : ['My Name',....],
colModel : [ {name:'myname',...}, ...],`

is equivalent to

`colModel : [ {name:'myname', label: 'My Name', ...}, ...],`

Kind Regards