# jqgrid dynamic columns and data by json

Tags: jqgrid

I new learned about jqgrid.I want create grid by dynamic data and columns.
 I asked [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16191160/jqgrid-dynamic-columns/16195679?noredirect=1#comment23255506_16195679) and read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277962/jqgrid-and-dynamic-column-binding) but i needed more examples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In comments to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16195679/315935) on your previous answer I described shortly the idea how you can change the column headers based on the data returned from the server. To make all more clear I prepared a demo for you.

I tried to make the demo mostly short and clear, so it has some restrictions:

- number of columns not changed in different responses from the server
- the formatters and the `width` of the column will be not changed in different responses from the server.

All the restrictions can be reduced or removed, but in your case the above restrictions are suffused. Moreover I wanted first describe the main idea of the implementation.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DynamicHeaderProperties.htm) has tree buttons above the grid which allows to reload data from the server, but from different URLs. After clicking on "Load Russian headers" button the headers on the grid will be dynamically changed with the texts from the server response and one will see the following picture

[image]

The format of the data is like below:

```js
{
    "model": {
        "c1": { "label": "Client" },
        "c2": { "label": "Date" },
        "c3": { "label": "Amount" },
        "c4": { "label": "Tax" },
        "c5": { "label": "Total" },
        "c6": { "label": "Paid" },
        "c7": { "label": "Shipped via" },
        "c8": { "label": "Notes" }
    },
    "data": [
        {"id": "10",  "cell": ["test",   "2007-10-01", "200.00", "10.00", "210.00", "true",  "TN", "note"  ] },
        {"id": "20",  "cell": ["test2",  "2007-10-02", "300.00", "20.00", "320.00", "false", "FE", "note2" ] },
        {"id": "30",  "cell": ["test3",  "2007-09-01", "400.00", "30.00", "430.00", "false", "FE", "note3" ] },
        {"id": "40",  "cell": ["test4",  "2007-10-04", "200.00", "10.00", "210.00", "true",  "TN", "note4" ] },
        {"id": "50",  "cell": ["test5",  "2007-10-31", "300.00", "20.00", "320.00", "false", "FE", "note5" ] },
        {"id": "60",  "cell": ["test6",  "2007-09-06", "400.00", "30.00", "430.00", "false", "FE", "note6" ] },
        {"id": "70",  "cell": ["test7",  "2007-10-04", "200.00", "10.00", "210.00", "true",  "TN", "note7" ] },
        {"id": "80",  "cell": ["test8",  "2007-10-03", "300.00", "20.00", "320.00", "false", "FE", "note8" ] },
        {"id": "90",  "cell": ["test9",  "2007-09-01", "400.00", "30.00", "430.00", "false", "TN", "note9" ] },
        {"id": "100", "cell": ["test10", "2007-09-08", "500.00", "30.00", "530.00", "true",  "TN", "note10"] },
        {"id": "110", "cell": ["test11", "2007-09-08", "500.00", "30.00", "530.00", "false", "FE", "note11"] },
        {"id": "120", "cell": ["test12", "2007-09-10", "500.00", "30.00", "530.00", "false", "FE", "note12"] }
    ]
}
```

The most important part of the JavaScript code is

```js
jsonReader: { root: "data" },
beforeProcessing: function (data) {
    var $self = $(this), model = data.model, name, $colHeader, $sortingIcons;
    if (model) {
        for (name in model) {
            if (model.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                $colHeader = $("#jqgh_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id + "_" + name));
                $sortingIcons = $colHeader.find(">span.s-ico");
                $colHeader.text(model[name].label);
                $colHeader.append($sortingIcons);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Full JavaScript used in the demo is below

```js
var $grid = $("#list");
$grid.jqGrid({
    url: "DynamicHeaderProperties.json",
    datatype: "json",
    colModel: [
        { name: "c1", width: 70 },
        { name: "c2", width: 80, align: "center", sorttype: "date",
            formatter: "date", formatoptions: {newformat: "m/d/Y"}, datefmt: "m/d/Y"},
        { name: "c3", width: 70, formatter: "number", align: "right",
            editrules: {required: true, number: true}, editable: true},
        { name: "c4", width: 60, formatter:"number", align: "right", editable: true,
            editrules:{required: true, number: true}},
        { name: "c5", width: 110, formatter: "number", align:"right",
            editrules:{required:true,number: true}, editable: true},
        { name: "c6", width: 80, align: "center", editable: true,
            formatter:"checkbox",edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: {value: "Yes:No", defaultValue: "Yes"}},
        { name: "c7", width: 110, align: "center", formatter: "select", editable: true,
            edittype: "select", editoptions: {value: "FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:Intim", defaultValue: "Intime"}},
        { name: "c8", width: 90, sortable: false, editable:true}
    ],
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [5,10,20],
    pager: "#pager",
    gridview: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    sortname: "c2",
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption: "Setting coloumn headers dynamicaly",
    jsonReader: { root: "data" },
    beforeProcessing: function (data) {
        var $self = $(this), model = data.model, name, $colHeader, $sortingIcons;
        if (model) {
            for (name in model) {
                if (model.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                    $colHeader = $("#jqgh_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id + "_" + name));
                    $sortingIcons = $colHeader.find(">span.s-ico");
                    $colHeader.text(model[name].label);
                    $colHeader.append($sortingIcons);
                }
            }
        }
    },
    loadonce: true,
    height: "auto"
});
$("#en").button().click(function () {
    $grid.jqGrid("setGridParam", {
        datatype: "json",
        url: "DynamicHeaderProperties.json",
    }).trigger("reloadGrid", {current: true});
});
$("#ru").button().click(function () {
    $grid.jqGrid("setGridParam", {
        datatype: "json",
        url: "DynamicHeaderPropertiesRu.json",
    }).trigger("reloadGrid", {current: true});
});
$("#de").button().click(function () {
    $grid.jqGrid("setGridParam", {
        datatype: "json",
        url: "DynamicHeaderPropertiesDe.json",
    }).trigger("reloadGrid", {current: true});
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much.Your example helped me to understand :-)

Comment: Can we implement here pagination?

Comment: @user1926138: Yes, of cause. The bove example uses `loadonce: true` and defines `rowNum`. Thus it uses *local* pagination automatically if the server return from `url` correct data: all items of data at once. The data have to be sorted on the server based on `sortname` and `sortorder`. If you use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork, which I develop, then one can add `forceClientSorting: true` additionally to `loadonce: true`. It allows to sort and optionally filter *locally* the data rturned from the server before displaying of the first page of the data.

Comment: @Oleg, Thanks for response. Can we do server side pagination as I have lots of data more than 10K ?

Comment: @user1926138: jqGrid can be used in many different ways *with or without* server side paging. You should just choose the corresponding parameters of the grid. The typical problem now is the choice when to use one and when another. The Roundtrip to the server and loading the page from the database is slowly in many cases as *local paging*. Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-5000-25-free-jqgrid.htm) with 5000 rows and test the time of *local* paging, sorting and filtering the data.

Comment: @user1926138: [Another test](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/performane-13-40000-20-free-jqgrid.htm) shows the performance of local paging, sorting and filtering of the grid with 40000 rows. It's good enough too in modern web browsers. Thus the choice for the best performance for the user depend ins't so easy. One have to know the whole scenario of usage to make the best choice.