# How to Change the ColModel with a function, using clearGridData,setGridParam and reloadGrid? JAVASCRIPT/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json, jqgrid, reload

well.... first i need how change the colmodel whith a function that is call for a SELECT because my grid have periods and have a change with a select (cost and tons).

This is my GRID

```
        $("#grid").jqGrid({
                            .......
                            .......
                            url:'example1.json',
                            datatype: "json",
                            colNames: NAMESCOL,
                            colModel: MODEL,
                            .......
                            .......
                            caption:"Example 1"         
        });
```

where NAMESCOL and MODEL is:

```
var NAMESCOL = ["plant","town","name plant","Total","period1","period2","period3"];



var MODEL = [{name:'id_plant',index:'id_plant',width: 40},
          {name:'id_town',index:'id_town',width: 80},
              {name:'name_plant',index:'name_plant',width: 110},
              {name:'tot_ton',index:'tot_ton',width: 50},
              {name:'ton_per1',index:'ton_per1',width: 50},
              {name:'ton_per2',index:'ton_per2',width: 50},
              {name:'ton_per3',index:'ton_per3',width: 50}];

var MODEL2 = [{name:'id_plant',index:'id_plant',width: 40},
          {name:'id_town',index:'id_town',width: 80},
              {name:'name_plant',index:'name_plant',width: 110},
              {name:'tot_cost',index:'tot_ton',width: 50},
              {name:'cost_per1',index:'cost_per1',width: 50},
              {name:'cost_per2',index:'cost_per2',width: 50},
              {name:'cost_per3',index:'cost_per3',width: 50}];
```

and my function is:

```
 function CHANGE(){
           .......
           .......
           jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('clearGridData');
           jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('setGridParam', {colModel: MODEL2});
           jQuery('#grid').trigger('reloadGrid');       
 }
```

and try using   jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('setGridParam', {data: MODEL2}); but only refreshes the same information.

:(

Comment: the code which you post have syntax error near `width: 110'` (twice). It should be fixed to probably ``width: 110``. Could you include examples of JSON response from the server? It's strange that you need to change `{name:'tot_ton',index:'tot_ton',width: 50}` to `{name:'tot_cost',index:'tot_ton',width: 50}` and not to `{name:'tot_cost',index:'tot_cost',width: 50}` for example. Do you make editing of the grid or you need just that jqGrid reads `tot_cost` instead of `tot_ton`?

Comment: @Oleg 
Thanks for the syntax error in the width,and the answer your question is "make  editing of the grid". , i already did the other way, was to put all the columns in the grid but are "playing" with the attribute HIDDEN, but I would like to resolve this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't included the format of `"JSON"` data returned from the server. An example of the data could clear many things. Moreover the knowledge of some other parameters like `datatype`, `loadonce` and `jsonReader` could be very important too. In any way I can give you some advises which should help to solve your problem.

First of all I recommend you don't specify any `index` property in the `colModel`. If no `index` property specified then jqGrid makes `index` property by copying of the value of the `name` property. Different values for `index` and `name` properties like

```
{name:'tot_cost',index:'tot_ton',width: 50}
```

are typically an error.

Seconds, the value of `name` property of `colModel` items will be used to construct `id` attributes of internal jqGrid structures and the properties of some internal JavaScript objects used by jqGrid. The values of `name` property need be just *different* (unique). To read the data for the column from the JSON input jqGrid uses `jsonmap` property (with some exceptions). Only if `jsonmap` property is not defined in `colModel` then the `name` property is used instead of `jsonmap`.

So if JSON input of jqGrid (the `rows` part typically) consists mostly from objects like

```
{"id_plant": ..., "id_town": ..., "name_plant": ..., "tot_ton": ..., ...}
```

you can use

```
jsonReader: {repeatitems: false}, // it can be skipped starting with jqGrid 4.4.5
colModel: [
    { name: "id_plant", width: 40 },
    { name: "id_town", width: 80 },
    { name: "name_plant", width: 110 },
    { name: "tot_ton" },
    { name: "ton_per1" },
    { name: "ton_per2" },
    { name: "ton_per3" }
]
cmTemplate: { width: 50 }, // default properties for colModel items
...
```

or for example

```
jsonReader: {repeatitems: false}, // it can be skipped starting with jqGrid 4.4.5
colModel: [
    { name: "c1", jsonmap: "id_plant", width: 40 },
    { name: "c2", jsonmap: "id_town", width: 80 },
    { name: "c3", jsonmap: "name_plant", width: 110 },
    { name: "c4", jsonmap: "tot_ton" },
    { name: "c5", jsonmap: "ton_per1" },
    { name: "c6", jsonmap: "ton_per2" },
    { name: "c7", jsonmap: "ton_per3" }
]
cmTemplate: { width: 50 }, // default properties for colModel items
...
```

It's important to understand that it's really difficult to change values of `name` properties of `colModel` (for example using `setColProp` method inside of `beforeProcessing` callback), but you can any time change the value of `jsonmap` property or specify the value of `jsonmap` property as a function. For example the following definition of the column `tot_ton` of `colModel` can solve your current problem:

```
{
    name: "tot_ton",
    jsonmap: function (obj) {
        return obj.tot_ton || obj.tot_cost;
    }
}
```

It try to read `tot_ton` from the item of input data. If the value of `tot_ton` is undefined (or `null` or `0`) then the value of `obj.tot_cost` will be used. Depend of the type of the data of the `tot_ton` (for example if it's value is integer which can be `0`) one can better use the following `jsonmap` instead:

```
{
    name: "tot_ton",
    jsonmap: function (obj) {
        return obj.tot_ton !== undefined ? obj.tot_ton : obj.tot_cost;
    }
}
```

I would recommend you to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19427444/315935) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16288582/315935) answers which show how one can adjust some grid options based on the JSON data returned from the server. If you place such adjustment in `beforeProcessing` callback then the processing of the server response will be done using *new settings*. In the way you can make jqGrid really dynamical.