# How to display a "Select" element in JQGrid, when not in Edit mode?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm aware of the `editype="select"` option, however, in order to see the Select, the user has to initiate an editing.

Instead, I just want the drop-down list to be displayed in the cell by default without the user having to start Editing.

What I've tried:
The html is returned from the the PHP function called by jQGrid AJAX:

```
<cell><select><option>Test</option></select></cell>
```

And I set the formatter of the column to "select"

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Please add the code you tried already

Comment: I simply printed a select element into the grid

Comment: @V0R73X what does the grid display if it's not showing the `select` box?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean under "The html is returned from the the PHP function called by JQGrid ajax". Do you use currently `editoptions.dataUrl`? It will be used **only during editing**. If you need to load the list of options for some columns you have to extend the main response which fill the grid with the list of options. I mean usage of `beforeProcess` like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17410568/315935) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16288582/315935)

Comment: You should provide more details what you do. For example the definition of the column in `cloModel` where you want to place `<select>`. One need more information about unclear Ajax calls used to load select. Are the list of options of the select *the same* in all cells of the column? What you need to do if the user changes an option in one cell?

Comment: I classicly populate it using $('#tablename').jqgrid({url:"asdasd"});

Comment: @V0R73X: Sorry, but *classically* one returns **pure JSON or pure XML data** in the response on `url` and **not HTML fragments** inside of the data for cells. I think that other people don't understand what you do and in which context one should consider your question. It would be helpful if you append the text of your question with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the sneakiest thing I have ever done in my life:
I changed the '<' characters to `&lt;` and changed the '>' characters to `&gt;` on the server side data.
This way, the data wouldn't be stripped of tags when received by jqgrid.
Then I made a custom formatter in which it replaced the html code with the actual characters, causing the data to be displayed correctly.

```
formatter: function(cellvalue, options, rowObject){ return cellvalue.replace("&lt;","<").replace("&gt;",">"); }
```

Boom! Done deal.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do it with `custom fortmatter` in a column model

```
{
name: 'MyCol', index: 'MyCol', formatter: customSelectboxRenderer
}
```

then

```
function customSelectboxRenderer(cellValue, opts, rowObject){
   return "<select>...</select>";//options can be prepared from some local array
}
```

Comment: What if the html is already written into the JQGrid and I just want it to display it as a Select?

Comment: @V0R73X, you cant simply change the html to select box. jQgrid provides the full control of rendering the cell. Please use it instead of showing the text and then converting to selct :)

Comment: But my data is already pulled during the initial ajax request and using the custom formatter would mean another ajax request for the Select box, and that't not efficient.

Comment: @V0R73X, keep those options data in local array when initial request made and use it

Comment: I doubt that would work, depends on WHEN the custom formatter will be called: After or Before gridComplete

Comment: Yup, just tested and it doesn't work since the formatter is called before the grid is done loading data.

Comment: @VOR73X..you can use the option formatter:select that Jqgrid supports by default.

Comment: @V0R73X, your edit `formatter: customSelectboxRenderer()` is wrong. its a handler to a function. so we need to remove `()` :)

Comment: @Murali You still haven't provided me a solution in which there's no need to make a separate ajax request from the one JQGrid calls initially.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you meant

```
<cell><select><option>Test</option></select></cell>
```

is the response returned for the cell in question.

I think you just have to strip out the cell tag and return that from your own custom formatter
something like

```
function customFormatter(cellValue, opts, rowObject){
   // Assuming that cellValue is <cell><select><option>Test</option></select></cell>

  return cellValue.replace(blah);
}
```

Or if you can change the value returned from the server for the cell, then I would try seeing if that works without a formatter, if it doesnt you would want to a create custom formatter that returns the cellvalue.

```
function customFormatter(cellValue, opts, rowObject){
  // Assuming that cellValue is <select><option>Test</option></select>
  return cellValue;
}
```

If my assumption is incorrect, please clarify.

Comment: It doesn't work since the formatter function is called before the ajax call for populating the data is done. I tested it to verify.

Comment: The formatter function is called for every row in your data.  I have used this technique before. I think what is happening is that you are not using local/json as your data source, instead the table is already marked up and you are adding the jqgrid to it, is that right?

Comment: Cell value is the data with all the html tags stripped out. E.g for the example above, it's just Test.