# Load jqgrid structure from server, not only data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqgrid

Is it possible to load from server via ajax JQGrid structure(columns) together with data ?
If possible, could you please show an example ?

Comment: Are you trying to define the grid before your AJAX call without defining the columns, or would it be an option to declare/define the grid AND columns after the call?

Comment: @AJ I need to define the grid columns right after the server call because it depends on some conditions that should be calculated on server side. On the client side I only have a grid object that each time should be populated/repopulated with different columns and data.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason why not, you just ned to do things (asynchronously) in the correct order, something like this (forgive the psuedo code)

```
var jqGridOptions = {
   /*  various options here */
}

$.ajax({
   url: jqGridStructureUrl
}).success(function(jqGridColumns){


    // Add the col model to the other options    
    jqGridOptions.colModel = jqGridColumns.colModel
    jqGridOptions.colNames = jqGridColumns.colNames

    // set up the jqGrid
    $j("#gridId").jqGrid(jqGridOptions)

})
```

This will get you part of the way there.  I guess you'll also be wanting to load Data via Ajax in which case you can set the "Data" option on the jqGrid settings to a callback function (this is not very well documented) - OR you could fire off TWO ajax calls, one for data and one for structure and then when they're BOTH back munge the two together and instantiate your grid object

Comment: Thank you so much ! I'd really appreciate if you extend your example with Data also. I mean in one ajax call, not two calls.

Comment: This is a good answer.  To do the data portion, I would define the grid with `datatype: 'local'`, set up your column data in an array object from the server, and then iterate through adding each row.

Answer (score 2):

You can create jqGrid with all hidden columns. You need create grid with large enough number of columns. The names of the columns (in `colModel`) can have some generic values like `"c1"`, `"c2"`, `"c3"` ... The response from the server can contains `colModel` information together with the data. Inside of `beforeProcessing` callback you can change `colModel` and set new column headers. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16288582/315935) demonstrates setting of column headers dynamically. The code column be simplified by usage `setLabel` method. [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19427444/315935) demonstrates how to use `setColProp` to set the most settings of `colModel` full dynamically. If you would combine the solution with the usage of `setColWidth` method which I posted in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20030652/315935) (see [here](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid-plugins/blob/master/jQuery.jqGrid.setColWidth.js) too) then you could create perfect solution.