# is there anyway to have multiple columns in jqgrid, read the same source data for dropdowns?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqgrid

I have a case where i have multiple columns in jqGrid that source the same list to populate the dropdown.

```
   { name: "Manager", index: "Manager", width: 120, editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { dataUrl: "/Person/GetSelectData" }, editrules: { required: false} },

  { name: "Delegate", index: "Delegate", width: 120, editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { dataUrl: "/Person/GetSelectData" }, editrules: { required: false} },
```

I wanted to see if there is a way to have tihs work above without two seperate ajax calls to the same action just to get the same list of data:

```
   dataUrl: "/Person/GetSelectData"
```

so I can call it once and have the list of items linked to both columns?  Is that possible in jqGrid?

Comment: I have no idea why some readers downvoted your question. I find the question interesting I'v wrote my answer with am implementation way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any implementation of what you want will mean some kind of caching of the data for `"/Person/GetSelectData"`. One way which I would prefer myself is the usage of `value` instead of `dataUrl`. The list of select values can be included *in the main response to the server* which fill the grid. In the case the action used in `url` can returns *additional data*. You can use the returned data inside of `value` defined as a function or you can set the `value` inside of `beforeProcessing` alternatively. To make my suggestion more clear I explain it on an example.

The first way: usage `value` as function. One can include the data which you returns typically in `"/Person/GetSelectData"` inside of main JSON response. For example you can use `userdata` (or any other extensions of the input data):

```
{
    "rows": [
        ...
    ],
    "userdata": {
        "Persons": "Bill:Bill;Oleg:Oleg;Leora:Leora"
    }
}
```

Then one could use

```
beforeProcessing: function (data) {
    var $self = $(this), userData = data.userdata, persons, selectOptions;
    if (userData && userData.Persons) {
        persons = userData.Persons;
        selectOptions = {
            searchoptions: { value: ":All;" + persons }, // for toolbar search
            stype: "select",
            editoptions: { value: persons },
            edittype: "select"
        };
        $self.jqGrid("setColProp", "Manager", selectOptions);
        $self.jqGrid("setColProp", "Delegate", selectOptions);
    }
}
```

By the way one can even use `formatter: "select"` for "Manager" and "Delegate" columns. It allows to use ids instead of names. For example

```
"Persons": "3:Bill;1:Oleg;2:Leora"
```

One should add `formatter: "select"` to `selectOptions` too. It allows to use ids `3`, `1` and `2` inside of the main data (`rows` part of JSON data). The standard way with the usage of `dataUrl` don't allow to use `formatter: "select"`.

I recommend you to read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17410568/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19427444/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20905940/315935) for more information about usage `beforeProcessing` for dynamic modification of the grid.