# stop reloading dropdowns after add

Tags: jqgrid

Here is the code of my dropdown.

```
  {
 name: 'ClassId', index: 'ClassId', align: 'center',editable: true, edittype: 'select',
 editoptions: {
 dataUrl:'@Url.Action("GetAllClasses", "Class", new { Area = "Curriculums"})',
 buildSelect: function (data) {
                     var response, s = '<select>', i;
                     response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                     //s += '<option value="0">--Select Class--</option>';
                     if (response && response.length) {
                         $.each(response, function (i) {
                      s += '<option value="' + this.Id + '">' + this.ClassName + '</option>';
                      });
                     }
                     return s + '</select>';
                 }
             }
          },
```

I am using form edit.I am reloading grid after insert.But the problem is after inserting data when I try to add another one my dropdowns are getting refreashed.I want that the dropdown selected value will be previously selected value.I don't want to change dropdown selected value on the second add.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way to prevent reloading of data from `dataUrl` could be setting Cache-Control HTTP header in the server response. Setting of `Cache-Control: max-age=60` in the server response for example will prevent reloading of data from the server during 60 sec. In case of ASP.NET MVC you can use `CacheControl` attribute for example (see `Duration` and `Location` properties).

One more alternative would be dynamical setting `editoptions.value` instead of usage `editoptions.dataUrl`. For example one can include the information needed for building `editoptions.value` as an extension of the standard response of the server for filling the grid. One can use `beforeProcessing` to process the part of the data. You will find the corresponding examples in the following cold answers: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21157272/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17410568/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19427444/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16288582/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20030652/315935) and other. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20905940/315935) describes in short one of the the possible scenario to create full dynamic grid.

Comment: thanks you very much.We are so lucky that you are on SO for help

Comment: @janina: Take a look in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21901410/315935). It's about the same subject and describes different implementation options.

Comment: this is working but dropdown selected value doesn't persist, it is getting changed on second Insert

Comment: @janina: Sorry, but I have no idea what you mean. I posted you references to many old answers with many **alternatives**. Which one you use? You wrote about "second Insert". What "insert" you mean? What will be changed?

Comment: Suppose I selected Class: Nine from my Dropdown and clicked Submit or Close Button.Now again if I click Add Button I can see that in my class dropdown, Class:Nine is not selected Now.It is now as it was first time loaded.How can I make the dropdown to persist the item which was previously selected?Thanks

Comment: I used both editoption.value and editoption.daturl but neither worked on the above issue.

Comment: @janina: 1) If you defined `editoption.value` then `editoption.dataUrl` will be ignored. 2) If you knows that adding of new row can modify possible values of your `editoption.value` then you can use for example [afterSubmit](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) callback of form editing to update `editoption.value` with respect of `setColProp`.

Comment: can setColProp will help here? What will be its job here?

Comment: @janina: `setColProp` helps to modify `colModel` parameters. Don't forget to use `recreateForm: true` option of form editing.