# Upgrade to Free jqGrid 4.11 - inline edit with edittype:'select' does not pass value of the select option

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

The grid defines the field as:

```
colModel: [
    {name:'Catalogue', index:'catalogue.Catalogue', width:100, align:"left",
        editable:true, edittype:'select',
        editoptions: {dataUrl:'xtras/selectOptions.php?optionFunction=CatalogueSelect'}
    },
```

The build grid with inline edit html code shows:

```
<select class="editable" id="23368_Catalogue" name="Catalogue" size="1">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="2064">KSCOPE370</option>
    <option value="2063">KSCOPE369</option>
...
</select>
```

I'm expecting the grid to pass to the server values of the `select` such as `[Catalogue] => 2064`, yet the grid sends to server:

```
[Catalogue] => KSCOPE370
```

If I add to column definition `formatter:'select',` - it sends the correct value of `2064`, however if I attempt the inline edit, then cancel it - the visible value of the `Catalogue` field disapears:
Was:

```
Catalogue    ISRC   ...
KSCOPE370   GBCQV0200197   .....
```

After cancel editing, becomes:

```
Catalogue    ISRC   ...
            GBCQV0200197   .....
```

What is the correct way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important to understand that the format of data in the grid have to corresponds the format of editing. The input data, which you use for the column `Catalogue` are the strings like `"KSCOPE370"` and `"KSCOPE369"` instead of ids `2064` or `2063`. It means that jqGrid hold `"KSCOPE370"`, but it means that the new modified data have to be in the save format: strings and not ids.

Your current code would fail if it would try try to save the value `2064` in the grid after editing. It saves `KSCOPE370` locally and send `Catalogue=KSCOPE370` to the server because you don't specified `formatter: "select"` to the column `Catalogue`. If one debug the code one can see that the new value will be correctly saved in the grid, but one have the problem on the server side. It seems that your server code expect ids instead of the text and can't process the data `Catalogue=KSCOPE370`. You use `.trigger("reloadGrid", [{current: true}])` in `aftersavefunc` of inline editing to reload the grid. The empty text will be displayed after reloading the grid.

jqGrid provide two main options: the usage of texts and the usage of ids. Typically one have database table which holds the lookup data. I personally create lookup tables always by usage `IDENTITY` (or [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp)) column for id and the column with the text. Additionally I create always [UNIQUE CONSTRAINT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp) on the text. It allows to be sure that one can not only get the text by id, but id by the text if it would be required. Because of that one can easy use the texts during filling and editing the grid. The id value can be resoled by name, whenever it's needed, on the server side.

If one really need to use ids during instead of text then you should

1. fill the grid with ids in the `Catalogue` instead of the texts.
2. one should use `formatter: "select"` to display the texts instead of the ids in the grid.
3. one can't use `editoptions.dataUrl` to provide the map between ids and the texts because `dataUrl` request will be processed using asynchronous Ajax request, but one need to have the map already for filling the grid. The `formatter: "select"` have to have the values. Thus one have to use `editoptions.value` instead of `editoptions.dataUrl`. The solution of the problem is described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19427444/315935) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21157272/315935). It suggests to return the `editoptions.value` value together with the main data of the grid and to use `beforeProcessing` to set `editoptions.value` before the value will be used by `formatter: "select"`. Such approach reduces additionally the HTTP traffic because one don't need to make request to `dataUrl` every time on editing of row.

**UPDATED:** I posted [the changes](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/ae5ec191544b9a0cb2f748252d4e6d6744d84e43) to GitHub to send `value` of `<option>` to the server even if no `formatter: "select"` is defined. It will still used the `text` for *local* editing. Such changes should improve the compatibility of free jqGrid to old versions of jqGrid.

Comment: I meet all the suggested criteria in my database: Use of unique `ID` with autoincrement, `Catalogue` field is unique too. So in other words interpreting your post - the grid only sends "visible" value of the field to the server. I can either use `editoptions.value` to send the select values to the grid while it is being build, where grid is going to store it. OR I have to lookup the `ID` of corresponding `Catalogue` at the server side. Correct?

Comment: @Elen: I mean that if you use no `formatter: "select"` and fill the grid with the data having `"KSCOPE370"` for the first column then `dataUrl` should generate select with the same `value` as the text: `<option value="KSCOPE370">KSCOPE370</option>` instead of `<option value="2064">KSCOPE370</option>` The server code, which corresponds `xtras/Records.php` should expect the text and not the id. During saving in the table you should just use `SELECT` in lookup table which convert the text `KSCOPE370` to the id `2064` which will be saved finally.

Comment: @Elen: The second way, which I described, is the way of filling the grid with ids like `2064` and editing the ids too.

Comment: Understood. With all the huge respect I have for you and your enormous work... why would you suppress the default `select` behaviour, where in normal html form `select` will pass the value of the selected option, not it's name?

Comment: @Elen: The old code of jqGrid is dirty. I rewrote of many parts and continue the work. For example it was many places in jqGrid (cell editing and inline editing), where one get texts or values from editing fields. I separated the method [getEditedValue](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.11.1/js/grid.base.js#L1231-L1300) which do this. It has `useTextInSelects` parameter and I set `selectMethod = useTextInSelects ? "text" : "val"` at the beginning of the code and use [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.11.1/js/grid.base.js#L1263) to get the value or the text.

Comment: right! so how can I force `useTextInSelects` to be `false` for a specific column?

Comment: @Elen: The parameter `useTextInSelects` will be set to `true` or `false` based of the existence of `formater` (typically `formatter: "select"`) in the corresponding column having `edittype:'select'`. What you write will mean the usage of `$.val()` method always instead of usage either `$.text()` or `$.val()`. Probably it would be correct too. One should just take in consideration all different use cases, which is not so simple.

Comment: If I may suggest... As non-experienced user I would expect the behaviour of `select` to be default as for simple HTML form. And in cases when I want to retrieve the text of the `select` - I should specify this explicitly...

Comment: @Elen: It would mean in your case that jqGrid would save `2064` instead of `KSCOPE370` in the cell after editing and one would be display correct value only after reloading the grid.

Comment: @Elen: The old code in jqGrid 4.6 from inline editing did [the following](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.inlinedit.js#L190-L204) then it used in [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.inlinedit.js#L283) and in [the lines](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.inlinedit.js#L328-L329). I have to look in the old code very carefully to understand what exactly will be send to the server and what should be used locally. The code just contains special hack for very special case: usage of `<option>` with text and values.

Comment: would be great! thank you! UPD: or both text and value can be sent to the server for user to choose

Comment: @Elen: You are welcome! One can't send both the text and the value to the server because the format of the value is `colName=newValue`. I will look in the code one more and probably will implement the sending to the server the value and the usage of text locally if no formatter are specified. I will inform you about it if I'll do the changes. Thank you for the discussion about the subject.

Comment: @Elen: I posted new changes to free jqGrid repository on GitHub. Now your demo works without any changes on the backend. See **UPDATED** part of my answer.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to write the code rather than having paragraphs?