# jqGrid setting colModels and colNames dynamically

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

Is it really necessary to unload `$("#myGrid").jqGrid('GridUnload');` if you want to set 
again its `colModels` and `colNames`? Or should i say is it the only way to implement 
a dynamic columns of jqGrid? Although I've tried that one and it worked.
But I also tried the `setGridParam` of jqGrid but it wont work when i put colModels/colNames.

This is what i did aside from unloading

```
    $.ajax({
            url     : url, //url the returns formatted colModels/colNames and other data
            data    : data, 
            async   : false,
            success : function(data){
            $("#myGrid").setGridParam({
                url : "xx/xxx/xx.json",
                page : 1,
                postData : {
               .
               .
               .
                },
                colNames : data.returnedColNames,
                colModel : data.returnedColModels,
                rowNum : 50,
                pager: '#myGridPager',
            }).trigger("reloadGrid");

            }
        });
```

But i get and error like `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'formatter' of undefined`

Any ideas on this approach? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's important to know whether **the number of column** will be changed. Do you know at least the maximal number of columns which could be in the dynamic grid?

Comment: Yes the number of columns will be changed. The max number of columns to be displayed is 10

Comment: in the case you can follow my answer.

Answer (score 2):

jqGrid creates some column structures during creating of the grid. If one created the grid once one can't change the number of columns for example. On the other side you can makes some unneeded columns hidden. Setting of `colModel` will not change the column headers. On the other side you can use `setLabel` method to change column headers dynamically. The most values of `colModel` can be changes. The main restriction is: the number of columns should be the same. Another restriction: you should not change the value of `name` property of columns because the property will be used to generates ids of column headers. If you use `repeatitems: false` style of data then you can dynamically set `jsonmap` or `xmlmap` property of columns holding `name` property unchanges. Changing of `width` property by `setGridParam` will not change the width of existing columns. On the other side you can use `setColWidth` method which I suggested in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20030652/315935) and which you can download from [here](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid-plugins). So you can creates grid with large enough number of columns and set the other columns as hidden.

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19427444/315935) provides 90% of solution which you asked. I modifies `colModel` inside of `beforeProcessing`. [Other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20905940/315935) contains short description of the solution which you need.