# Is JQuery.JqGrid plugin for MVC which is available inside the Nuget free

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have asp.net mvc5 web application. add i find that jquery.jqGrid is available for free inside the Nuget package manager as follow:-

[image]

I thought that jQuery.jqGrid is not available for free as on their web site they have a section for buying the plugin http://jqgrid.com/jqgrid/jqgrid-asp-net-mvc  ? so can anyone adivce on this ? is it free or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version https://www.nuget.org/packages/Trirand.jqGrid/4.6.0 is definitively free. See

[image]

You can download jqGrid 4.7.0 from [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/tree/v4.7.0) too. The code is published under "Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses". See the first lines of the file [jquery.jqGrid.min.js](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.7.0/js/minified/jquery.jqGrid.min.js) and the comments at the beginning of every JavaScript file included in the package. *The version is not published on NuGet.*

There are some forks of the last free version of jqGrid. See for example [my fork](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid), [this one](https://github.com/openpsa/grid.js) or another. I have fixed already (in my fork) many bugs existing in the last free version of jqGrid. I have implemented many new features too. I think that I and other developers will cooperate together to continue developing of free version of jqGrid.

I plan to release the currently developing version soon (probably already in January). I will publish it on NuGet and other common known free repositories.

Comment: so can you adivce if currently i can use the https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid inside my asp.net mvc web application , or it is still not completed yet? second question is there sufficient documentation about this ?

Comment: now i am bit confused. If i want to use jqGrid inside my new asp.net mvc-5 web application, which link i should use to download the related files ? and is it free or not ? can you please adivce ? SECOND question. Is there  specific jqGrid which is designed to work with asp.net mvc framework, for example to support data annotations, html helpers , model binder , etc... ? thanks

Comment: @johnG: It's too many questions at once. You can download **free** version of the current state of development of jqGrid from [github](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid). **All features existing in jqGrid 4.7 work in new version**. [The changes]( https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid/commits/master) contains short comments. You can just include `grid.locale-en.js` and `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` in your project and to place `jquery.jqGrid.min.map` and `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` in the same directory with `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`.

Comment: @johnG: More readable description of the full list of bug fixes and new features I will create soon. An example of one new feature you can see in tree demos: [this one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/autoresizeOnLoad.htm), [this one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/autoresizeOnDoubleClickOnColumnResizerWithShrink.htm), [this one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/autoresizeOnDoubleClickOnColumnResizer.htm) and [this one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/autoresizeOnDoubleClickOnColumnResizer1.htm).

Comment: @johnG: All the demos uses new `setColWidth` and `autoResizeColumn` methods. The columns having `autoResizable: true` property (which can be set by usage of `cmTemplate: { autoResizable: true }` makes the column "resizable to the optimal column size". Try to make double-click on the column resizer (between two column headers). The width of the column will be changed. The demos uses different other options and the resizing behavior is a little other. All other will be done later... I'm still in the process of development.

Comment: thanks for the reply, so all these new features are available inside this link https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid ? or i need to wait for couple of weeks to get a stable version of jqGrid (you mentioned at the end of January ?)

Comment: SECOND question. Is there specific jqGrid which is designed to work with asp.net mvc framework, for example to support data annotations, html helpers , model binder , etc... ? thanks

Comment: @johnG: free open source jqGrid was always pure JavaScript solution (jQuery plugin). So it could not have any support of data annotations, html helpers, model binder. Your original question was: which version of jqGrid (pure JavaScript) could be find on NuGet. The questions about design patterns of usage jqGrid, the usage of JavaScript components in MVC model and other design and implementation questions could take really much time and couldn't be answered shortly in comments. There are some so MVC based solutions, but all have disadvantaged in my opinion which can't be shortly described.

Comment: can you please mentioned some of these MVC based solutions ? and what type of disadvantages they have ?

Comment: @johnG: Probably the best free solution which I know is [Lib.Web.Mvc](https://github.com/tpeczek/Lib.Web.Mvc), but I don't follow the implementation way. All MVC wrapper solution need be updated to use new features. If you start to use MVC wrapper to jqGrid you can easy generate good C# code, but very bad the same code *could* (not must) generate slow JavaScript code because you will don't analyse and understand what JavaScript code will be executed. Some remarks about my point of view on the problem you can read in [the recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27732617/315935).

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, it is very helpful. You know this have been the worth experience i have ever faced, which is to find a suitable grid that does not break the asp.net MVC architecure. seems everything around does not help. i will try the Lib.Web.MVC , but can you advice about any problems i might face when using Lib.Web.MVC inside my asp.net mvc web application ? so that i can be aware of it ?

Comment: second question, does Lib.Web.MVC supports server side processing for paging, filtering, sorting, etc . as i could not find this info inside the documentations ?

Comment: @johnG: I think that creating Controller Action which provides all data for the grid will not break architecture of MVC. I don't see that one should strong follow any architecture pattern at all. The most advantage of it was the possibility to create unit tests. You can test action controller in the way too. Server side paging sorting and filtering can be implemented without any helpers like I've shown in [the old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5501644/315935) for example. I recommend you do use **client side sorting** in case of number of rows less as 1000 or even a little more.

Comment: @johnG: I tried Lib.Web.MVC many years before last time. So I can't really help you here, but it seems to me that the demo example from http://tpeczek.codeplex.com/releases/view/62741 already used server side paging and sorting/filtering. Sorry, but I don't want to continue the long common architecture discussion because it can take really a lot of time.

Comment: thanks for the link but i can not find relevant documentation about using Li.web.mvc on this link and also the available resources all over the web is very brief ... can you advice from where i can get a full documentation about lib.web.mvc and how i can apply the server side processing to it ?  because i need to test it inside my test application .. thanks

Comment: @johnG: I repeat that **I tried Lib.Web.MVC many years before last time**. You can ask any *new questions* about Lib.Web.MVC by marking the question with the tag [lib.web.mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/lib.web.mvc/info) or to post the question on github:  https://github.com/tpeczek/Lib.Web.Mvc. In any way you should not expect to have full documentation to the product which you get for free with the full source code.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from the link in your question :

> Free and Business Edition
>
> Both versions have the full functionality and are licensed for
>   commercial use.
>
> The free version is branded with Codemerx logo and its code is
>   obfuscated. Support response time is 72 hours for the free version.
>
> The commercial version is not branded and its code is not obfuscated.
>   Support response time is 24 hours for the commercial version.

I'm guessing it's the free version with branded logo.

Comment: so what does this exactly mean ? where the logo will be displayed ? and can i remove it?