# set colmodel of jqGrid when rows loaded from server but before add to grid

Tags: dynamic, jqgrid, dynamic-columns, col

I want to change my grid's colmodel dynamiclly and I did lots of search but non of the question thread answered me. I need to pivot a select in sql so after I execute my query I find out names and count of my grid's columns.

In other posts I find the way of changing the colmodel but I don`t know when and where I must do it. It is not possible to execute query two time becuase It may changed in result and decrease performance.

Comment: You are strongly encouraged to include what you have tried so far. It is always a good idea to include code that people can start of from. Stackoverflow is not a code-writing-service and people usually react sensitive to such questions.

Answer (score 0):

One can use `beforeProcessing` callback to make many modifications in `colModel` dynamically. One can't add/remove columns and one can't modify `name` property, but the most other changes are allowed. I would recommend you to use `setColProp` method to make the modification. One can use `setLabel` to modify column headers. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19427444/315935), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16288582/315935) and [the another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17410568/315935) provides corresponding examples.

I am working now on `addColumn`/`removeColumn` column methods which will allow to modify `colModel` more deep. You can find the current beta version of `addColumn` with the corresponding demos on [github](https://github.com/OlegKi/jqGrid-plugins).