# making the column names dynamic in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

guys i want the column names to be dinamic in case it is changed so i dont have to put it namually .. here is my code

```js
jqGrid11.prototype = {
 display : function() {
  $('body').append(this.html.join(""));

  $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
   url : "index.jsp",
   colModel : [ {

    label : 'Department Name',
    name : 'Department Name ',
    width : 200
   }, {
    label : 'id',
    name : 'id',
    key : true,
    width : 200
   }, {
    label : 'Employees',
    name : 'Employees ',
    width : 500

   } ],
   viewrecords : true,
   width : 780,
   height : 250,
   rowNum : 20,
   pager : "#jqGridPager"
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
   $("#jqGrid").jqGrid("addRowData", i + 1, this.data[i]);
  }

 }
};
```

so i want the department name and id and employee to be generated dynamically

Comment: do you have a source of data for dynamic columns? like http response in JSON array?

Comment: yes .. i have a json array

Comment: I think the answer you are looking is something like this - [stackoverflow jqgrid-and-dynamic-column-binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277962/jqgrid-and-dynamic-column-binding)

Answer (score 1):

You should **never ever** use `name` property of `colModel`, which contains spaces. The `name` will be used to construct ids of some elements and spaces are prohibited by `HTML5` for ids.

You should never ever fill the grid using `addRowData` in the loop. It's the slowest way to fill the grid.

You use `url : "index.jsp"` without specifying `datatype`. It defaults to use `datatype: "xml"`. On the other hand, you wrote that you want to use JSON as input.

If you have input data as array of items (`this.data`) then you should use `datatype: "local", data: this.data`, which will create jqGrid *with the data* and display the first page of the data (base on `rowNum: 20`).

I'd recommend you to verify which version of jqGrid and from which fork of jqGrid you use. I recommend you to use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.13.2 - the current version of free jqGrid fork, which I develop.